# Value of the python list changes

Tags: python

I have string processing function which takes 3 parameters:

1. String1 , ex: "A"
2. String2, ex : "B"
3. python list of strings

Use case: To iterate over a list of tuples (String) to pass the first 2 parameters of the function above, and throughout the entire iteration (the python list which contains the current configuration of the strings SHOULD NOT change).

code:

```
stringList = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
inputList = itertools.permutations(stringList, 2)
list_that_should_not_change = deepcopy(stateConfig)

#stackBlockforuser - string processing function
for each in inputList:
   postchangeList = stackBlockforuser(each[0],each[1], list_that_should_not_change)
```

The error is after one iteration, the 3rd parameter to the string function changes to the postchangeList (the output of the string processing function). Any suggestions no how to stop the list from changing.

Comment: Unless you provide the code for `stackBlockforuser`, we have no idea what is happening.

Comment: @Prune the entire code is too big. Moreover, I was struck in this particular problem where the value of my python list was changing during the iteration. Hence I gave the snippet after confirming through loggers, which is causing the issue. I got the exact solution I was looking for from a gentleman. So if you feel you contribute something please comment or answer the post, or please get off my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is modifying the input list, so keep passing new copies of `stateConfig` to it. Keep in mind that a string is immutable, so you probably don't need a deep copy:

```
for each in inputList:
    postchangeList = stackBlockfouser(*each, stateConfig[:])
```

I've also taken the liberty of using star expansion on your loop variable.

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned, maybe:

```
def stackBlockforuser(first, second, your_list):
    new_list = your_list[:]  # or list(your_list)
    ...
```